# Rest services on Shared Host and Localhost

Tags: php, rest

I'm making a Rest services, using PHP + Zend Framework 1. I test on localhost( with XAMPP), it ok. But when i move source code to my shared host, i can't make a PUT and DELETE request. It say that

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /v1/image/1 on this server.

So, how to fix it or can't use shared host to make a Rest services?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by add following into .htaccess

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Limit>
```